# is there a way to know how many record are written by kafka connect sink?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I use the HDFS sink connector and I want to know how many record are put to HDFS.

In logs I have log when the connector start to put file to HDFS, but not how many record there are.
For exemple :

```
INFO Opening record writer for: hdfs://hdfs/path/+tmp/table/partition=2020-02-27/19955b52-8189-4f70-94b5-46d579cd1505_tmp.avro (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroRecordWriterProvider)
```

Is it possible by extending the connector itself ?

I use kafka connect HDFS 2 sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, not that I know of (of course, it's open source, and you could look). Each file would have variable amount of data, so metric tracking wouldn't be all too useful.

I cannot recall if debug or trace logs expose that information.

You can can use Hive/Spark/HDFS CLI to inspect each file, though